# How do pull no fast-forward in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit, fast-forward

Since some people recommend no fast-fordward (--no-ff) on merges in Git, I wanted to do that. But I can't see where to check to enable that in the TortoiseGit GUI.

Yes, I could do this from the command line. But others in the group won't use it, so I need a GUI solution.

EDIT: removed push from question; it is not realistic as pointed out below. The references were to pulls only.

Comment: Beware of the `no-ff` option: it will create "checkpoint commits" that will break any bisect or blame attempt. See http://sandofsky.com/blog/git-workflow.html

Comment: As I understand it, it doesn't create them. It just leaves them in if you created them yourself. If you ensure that every commit has the code at a usable state then there should be no problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where do you search for it? When selecting TortoiseGit -> Merge menu item I get dialog shown below. I can't believe that you missed "No Fast Forward" check box on it :)

[image]

For `pull` there's no such option in TortoiseGit, but you can do `fetch` and then `merge` with 'No Fast Forward' option from the GUI manually. Net result would be the same.

Comment: How about on push and pull, however?

Comment: @Brian: `push` doesn't have that option even on command-line. Do you really need new merge commit _each time_ you do `pull`? Why? For `merge` I can understand your concern, but for `pull`... Could you explain, please?

Comment: @Brian: It seems that for pull TortoiseGit doesn't have such option, but you could always do fetch and then merge with no-ff option - both from the GUI.

Comment: put that comment about fetch, then merge in the answer so it is easier for others to find. Then I will accept that answer.

Comment: @Brian: added to answer. I think that it is almost equally easy to find details in comments though :)