# Log Graph in TortoiseGit not showing branch/merge?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit

I have just started using Git on Windows. I am hosting on BitBucket and using TortoiseGit as the windows client.

Things are moving in the right directon, but I am clueless at a point. I was working on the master branch, and at one point created a new branch. Then I continued working on the new branch and kept committing, pushing. Finally when I was done, I merged this new branch(codetidy) back into master.

Now when I do 'Show Log' and select 'All Branches', I just get a straight line in the graph. There is no information of from when a branch was taken out, and when it merged back. Please hep me find this information.

[image: Version graph]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's probably because your merge was a *fast-forward* merge, which means that there weren't any commits made to `master` in between the time when `codetidy` was created and when it was merged back in - so Git helpfully just moves `master` to point to the same commit (because it already has the exact same file contents as what a merge would look like), rather than creating an unnecessary merge commit.

If you don't want this behavior, you'd need to force Git to create a separate merge commit - on the command line, this is done with `git merge --no-ff`. In TortoiseGit, it's done via checking the "No Fast Forward" checkbox in the merge window (see [this previous StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6893363/148870) for a screenshot).

Comment: yes, you are right. There was no commit on master. This sounds a wise thing done by git. But as git moved master to point to latest commit if codetidy, what if I now finally delete the branch as practically i have merged and am done with the branch?

Comment: Then `master` will remain pointing to the same place both branches currently point. Branches in Git are simply pointers to commits; currently you have two pointers pointing to the same commit. If you delete one of the pointers, the other will still point to that commit.